# Attach data-id to text function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on the box i need to change score, but only in what box which i clicked, but now it changes on the all my boxes in the loop. I have group_id which box is clicked but, how i can join to the text() function this group_id or what solution is good for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/9zx38y9g/2/

```
<div data-group="1" class="score">
   <!-- PHP loop -->
   <i data-nr="1" class="list"></i>
   <i data-nr="2" class="list"></i>
   <i data-nr="3" class="list"></i>
   <span class="list-score">25</span>
</div>

<div data-group="2" class="score">
   <!-- PHP loop -->
   <i data-nr="1" class="list"></i>
   <i data-nr="2" class="list"></i>
   <i data-nr="3" class="list"></i>
   <span class="list-score">18</span>
</div>

$('.list').click(function() {
   var group_id = $(this).closest('.score').data('group');
   $('.list-score').text(250);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` the element in the parent element context.

```
$('.list').click(function() {
    var score = $(this).closest('.score');
    score.find('.list-score').text(250);
    //var group_id = score.data('group');

    //.siblings() method can also be used
    $(this).siblings('.list-score').text(250);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1nkxgyq5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use find() method to find .list-score element. Try this:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L5v6qbyd/

```
$('.list').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.score').find('.list-score').text(250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.list').click(function() {
    var group_id = $(this).closest('.score').data('group');
    $(this).nextAll('.list-score').text($(this).data('nr'));

  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid navy;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-group="1" class="score">
    <!-- PHP loop -->
    <i data-nr="1" class="list"></i>
    <i data-nr="2" class="list"></i>
    <i data-nr="3" class="list"></i>
    <span class="list-score">25</span>
</div>

<div data-group="2" class="score">
    <!-- PHP loop -->
    <i data-nr="1" class="list"></i>
    <i data-nr="2" class="list"></i>
    <i data-nr="3" class="list"></i>
    <span class="list-score">18</span>
</div>
```